# How to implement abbreviation search to SearchView

Tags: android, kotlin, searchview, android-search, android-searchmanager

I have a `Fragment` containing a list of strings (company names) which works with `SearchView`. However, due to many companies having long names, is there a way where I can type in an abbreviation for a company name rather than having to type in the whole company name? 'FTSE 150' and 'FTSE 250' are self-explanatory hence don't need abbereviations.

**Abberviations for company names**

- GSK - GlaxoSmithKline plc
- HSX - Hiscox Ltd
- IHG - InterContinental
  Hotels Group plc
- MKS - Marks & Spencer Group plc

**strings.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="company_names">
        <item>@string/glaxosmithkline_plc</item>
        <item>@string/hiscox_ltd</item>
        <item>@string/intercontinental_hotels_group_plc</item>
        <item>@string/marks_and_spencer_group_plc</item>
        <item>@string/ftse_150</item>
        <item>@string/ftse_250</item>
    </string-array>

    <string name="glaxosmithkline_plc">GlaxoSmithKline plc</string>
    <string name="hiscox_ltd">Hiscox Ltd</string>
    <string name="intercontinental_hotels_group_plc">InterContinental Hotels Group plc</string>
    <string name="marks_and_spencer_group_plc">Marks &amp; Spencer Group plc</string>
    <string name="ftse_150">FTSE 150</string>
    <string name="ftse_250">FTSE 250</string>
</resources>
```

**fragment class**

```
class MyFragment : androidx.fragment.app.Fragment() {

    private var mAdapter: MyListAdapter? = null

    private lateinit var mRecyclerView: androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView

    private var mTwoPane: Boolean = false

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setHasOptionsMenu(true)
    }

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_recyclerview, container, false)
        mTwoPane = (activity as androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity).findViewById<View>(R.id.detail_container) != null

        mRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView_list)
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)
        mRecyclerView.layoutManager = androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager(this.activity)
        mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(androidx.recyclerview.widget.DividerItemDecoration(Objects.requireNonNull<Context>(context), LinearLayout.VERTICAL))

        val myList = ArrayList<Companies>()

//        val items = resources.getStringArray(R.array.company_names)
//        for (n in items) {
//            val company = Companies(0, "", "")
//            myList.add(company)
//        }

        val companyA = Companies(1, "GlaxoSmithKline plc", "GSK")
        val companyB = Companies(2, "Hiscox Ltd", "HSX")
        val companyC = Companies(3, "InterContinental Hotels Group plc", "IHG")
        val companyD = Companies(4, "Marks & Spencer Group plc", "MKS")
        val companyE = Companies(5, "FTSE 150", "")
        val companyF = Companies(6, "FTSE 250", "")

        val myList = DatabaseHandler(this.context!!)
        myList.insertData(companyA)
        myList.insertData(companyB)
        myList.insertData(companyC)
        myList.insertData(companyD)
        myList.insertData(companyE)
        myList.insertData(companyF)

        mAdapter = MyListAdapter(activity!!, myList, mTwoPane)

        mRecyclerView.adapter = mAdapter

        return view
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, inflater: MenuInflater) {
        val mInflater = Objects.requireNonNull<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity>(activity).menuInflater
        mInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_search, menu)

        val searchView = searchitem.actionView as SearchView

        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(object : SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
            override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String): Boolean {
                return false
            }

            override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String): Boolean {
                mAdapter!!.filter.filter(newText)
                return false
            }
        })

        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater)
    }
}
```

**MyListAdapter class**

```
class MyListAdapter(private val mCtx: Context, private val myList: MutableList<Companies>,
                          private val
mTwoPane: Boolean) : androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.Adapter<MyListAdapter
.CompanyViewHolder>(), Filterable {
    private var myListFull = myList.toMutableList()

    private val companyFilter = object : Filter() {
        override fun performFiltering(constraint: CharSequence?): Filter.FilterResults {
            val filteredList = ArrayList<Companies>()

            when {
                constraint == null || constraint.isEmpty() -> filteredList.addAll(myListFull)
                else -> {
                    val filterPattern = constraint.toString().toLowerCase().trim { it <= ' ' }

                    for (item in myListFull) {
                        when {
                            item.companyName!!.toLowerCase().contains(filterPattern) ->
                                filteredList.add(item)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            val results = Filter.FilterResults()
            results.values = filteredList
            return results
        }

        override fun publishResults(constraint: CharSequence?, results: Filter.FilterResults?) {
            myList.clear()
            myList.addAll(results!!.values as List<Companies>)
            notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
    }

    inner class CompanyViewHolder(itemView: View) : androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    .ViewHolder(itemView) {
        var tvTitle: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_RVItem)
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): CompanyViewHolder {
        val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mCtx)
        val v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_item_textview, parent, false)
        return CompanyViewHolder(v)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CompanyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val product = myList[holder.adapterPosition]

        holder.tvTitle.text = product.companyfuName
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return myList.size
    }

    override fun getFilter(): Filter {
        return companyFilter
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

**UPDATES**

**Custom model class**

```
data class Companies (val id: String, val fullName: String, val abbreviation: String)
```

**updated Adapter class**

```
class MyListAdapter(private val mCtx: Context,
                    private val mCompanies: MutableList<Companies>,
                    private val mTwoPane: Boolean) : androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.Adapter<MyListAdapter
.CompanyViewHolder>(), Filterable {
    private val mCompaniesFull = mCompanies.toMutableList()

    private val companyFilter = object : Filter() {
        override fun performFiltering(constraint: CharSequence?): Filter.FilterResults {
            val filteredList = if (constraint == null || constraint.isEmpty()) {
                mCompanies
            } else {
                val filterText = constraint.toString()
                mCompanies.filter { it.companyName.matchesIgnoreCase(filterText) || it.companyAbbreviation.matchesIgnoreCase(filterText) }
            }

            val results = Filter.FilterResults()
            results.values = filteredList
            return results
        }

        override fun publishResults(constraint: CharSequence?, results: Filter.FilterResults?) {
            mCompanies.clear()
            mCompanies.addAll(results!!.values as List<Companies>)
            notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
    }

    private fun String.matchesIgnoreCase(otherString: String): Boolean {
        return this.toLowerCase().contains(otherString.trim().toLowerCase())
    }

    inner class CompanyViewHolder(itemView: View) : androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    .ViewHolder(itemView) {
        var tvTitle: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_RVItem)
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): CompanyViewHolder {
        val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mCtx)
        val v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_item_textview, parent, false)
        return CompanyViewHolder(v)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CompanyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val product = mCompanies[holder.adapterPosition]
        holder.tvTitle.text = product.companyName
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return mCompanies.size
    }

    override fun getFilter(): Filter {
        return companyFilter
    }
}
```

**updated Fragment class**

```
class MonFragment : androidx.fragment.app.Fragment() {

    private var mAdapter: MyListAdapter? = null

    private lateinit var mRecyclerView: androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView

    private var mTwoPane: Boolean = false

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setHasOptionsMenu(true)
    }

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_recyclerview, container, false)
        mTwoPane = (activity as androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity).findViewById<View>(R.id.detail_container) != null

        mRecyclerView = view.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recyclerView_list)
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)
        mRecyclerView.layoutManager = androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager(this.activity)
        mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(androidx.recyclerview.widget.DividerItemDecoration(Objects.requireNonNull<Context>(context), LinearLayout.VERTICAL))

        mCompanies.add(Companies("GlaxoSmithKline plc", "GSK"))
        mCompanies.add(Companies("Hiscox Ltd", "HSX"))
        mCompanies.add(Companies("InterContinental Hotels Group plc", "IHG"))
        mCompanies.add(Companies("Marks & Spencer Group plc", "MKS"))
        mCompanies.add(Companies("FTSE 150", ""))
        mCompanies.add(Companies("FTSE 250", ""))

        mAdapter = MyListAdapter(activity!!, mCompanies, mTwoPane)

        mRecyclerView.adapter = mAdapter

        return view
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, inflater: MenuInflater) {
        val mInflater = Objects.requireNonNull<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity>(activity).menuInflater
        mInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_search, menu)

        val searchitem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search)
        val searchView = searchitem.actionView as SearchView

        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(object : SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
            override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String): Boolean {
                return false
            }

            override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String): Boolean {
                mAdapter!!.filter.filter(newText)
                mAdapter!!.notifyDataSetChanged()

                return false
            }
        })

        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater)
    }
}
```

Comment: please share MyListAdapter and specifically it's filter property impl. You would have to do the magic there

Comment: @JakubLicznerski Added :-)

Comment: Why don't you want to add one field with abbreviations and fill it with data? Then search for any of two fields.

Comment: @CoolMind I'm trying to minimise eye movement when reading the data. Not helpful particularly for longer names just to see 3 digits afterwards. Also, dozens more names will be added in future.

Comment: You don't have to show second field, only first. But search for both.

Comment: @CoolMind Do the abbreviations need to be in `strings.xml` even though they're not translatable?

Comment: I didn't read the code, but I think you have a database with strings. So you can read data from two fields of the database. `strings.xml` is intended for constant resources, it cannot be changed until application upgrade.

Comment: As @CoolMind said `strings.xml` most problably is not great solution for you, but if you need to use it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4960071/6752997) is an answer to similar question.

Comment: @JakubLicznerski, great! I think, you should create an answer here.

Comment: @CoolMind I don't have any databases as I want my app to work without an internet connection.

Comment: Then you can create a HashMap with strings as @JakubLicznerski advised. Or an ArrayList of classes, containing id, title and abbreviation.

Answer (score 1):

Following the discussion in comments I'd suggest two approaches for storing the data:

1. Device storage either with [SharedPreferences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624280/how-to-use-sharedpreferences-in-android-to-store-fetch-and-edit-values/3624358#3624358) or databases: [SQLite](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/sqlite), [Room](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room) (they are lightweight local storage databases, Internet connection is not needed).
2. Device memory (*not recommended*) as a List of hardcoded objects initialized either in `MainActivity` or `Fragment`'s `onCreate` method (dependent on the usage).

As @CoolMind suggested you should implement a custom model class `CompanyName(id, fullName, abbreviation)` and then filter by the alternative of `fullName` and `abbreviation`.

**EDIT:**
In `MyListAdapter` get rid of `myListFull` as it does nothing and put:

```
private val stockFilter = object : Filter() {
        override fun performFiltering(constraint: CharSequence?): Filter.FilterResults {
            val filteredList = if (constraint == null || constraint.isEmpty()) myList
                else {
                   val filterText = constraint.toString()
                   myList.filter { it.fullName.matchesIgnoreCase(filterText ) || it.abbreviation.matchesIgnoreCase(filterText) }
                }
            val results = Filter.FilterResults()
            results.values = filteredList
            return results
        }
}
```

Also add in the `MyListAdapter` class this extension function:

```
private fun String.matchesIgnoreCase(otherString: String): Boolean {
    return this.toLowerCase().contains(otherString.trim().toLowerCase())
}
```

Comment: I have tried the 1st suggestion but I still don't understand how to show inserted data in the RecyclerView.

Comment: Unresolved reference 'fullName' and 'abbreviation'.

See my updated code.

Comment: Because you use a class named `Stock` in filter, in `DatabaseHandler` you have `Tasks` and `Companies` I believe it all should be `CompanyName` or better `Company` which is the suggested model class... there is big mess in the code you posted, so it's hard to guess. I've posted a solution proposition which you should adjust to your code not copy-paste.

Comment: What about the **Code for concern** section? Surely that code would need to change as I'm not using a string array but a database helper instead.

Comment: the idea is to get rid of `strings.xml` 100% and query the database instead of `resources.getStringArray(R.array.stock_names)`

Comment: the idea is to get rid of `strings.xml` 100% and query the database instead of `resources.getStringArray(R.array.stock_names)`. So a method `getTask` should be changed to return `Company` objects.

Comment: In the `getTask` method, the parentheses in `val companies = Companies()` return this error: `No value passed for parameters 'id', 'fullName' and 'abbreviation'`. What values should be passed here?

Comment: Look up how **data classes**, it's **properties** and **val**s work in Kotlin, Also take a look at Kotlin's **constructor syntax**

Comment: Ok, I'm still a bit lost with the for loop at the bottom of my question, what should be used instead of `null`?

Comment: This again brings the **nullable type** into consideration, but I don't think its the right approach. You should assign all the data at once in the constructor (prior saving intermediate values in **val**s). I strongly recommend you to read *thoroughly* this [reference](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-syntax.html)

Comment: Do you mean the constructor of the `fragment`?

Comment: no, the constructor of `Company` class in `getCompany` method... exactly where the error appears...

Comment: The fragment class code has been updated. I changed 'Stock' to 'Companies' for easier readability. I created the table rows in the `onCreateView` method of the `Fragment` as I want to use the same `DatabaseHandler` for future data sets. Is there a way to use those rows in the `Fragment` whilst ensuring that the data can be filtered by `fullName` and `abbreviation`?

Comment: I believe it's a material for another question, but I'd recommend extracting the list filtering logic which you have in `MyListAdapter` to separate file and import the function which does filtering (returns a list based on a given list) and use it when you like. Meanwhile I'd kindly ask you to mark this answer as *accepted* and add a point if it helped you.

Comment: @MacaronLover did you run to some other additional problems? What is the cause of an unaccept? As I've invested time in helping you here I'd be asking for an upvote too if you don't mind.

Comment: Unfortunately, I did - the filter works as I type in letters, but afterwards when I delete those letters, the list does not return to its original state (i.e. show the whole list).

Comment: thats weird, try debugging inside the filter (see if it is actually called after removing a letter) and check the contents of `constraint`. Also contents of `myList` should remain unchanged

Comment: `val filteredList = if (constraint == null || constraint.isEmpty()) mCompanies constraint: "p"` appears when I type in a letter, but nothing happens when I remove the letter.

Comment: do you use the filter in `onTextChanged` as the author of this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18109744/android-search-in-listview-not-working-properly?

Comment: I'm not using `onTextChanged`. I'm using the code that you suggested. You were saying to get rid of `myListFull`. Would I need to use `val filteredList = ArrayList<Companies>()`?

Comment: Well then I can't tell how do you intercept the text change event because you didn't share this piece of code. I will advise you do it just like it is descibed in the post (only the part with `onTextChanged` method and apply it to your filter as it is right now)

Comment: I actually have. See the latest code to my question.